Loading razor pages from other domains
We are developing a "Portal" type app with Blazor and we want to be able to have several "projects" (for exampleintegrations or forms) that sit on other URLs. (Think like azure web apps)
so we might have
Portal.ourcompany.com - our portal app, which has a menu + header etc, and loads razor pages as part of the page in a separate container. This app is a client side webassembly app. We use .net 8.
then we might have https://ourcompanyintegrationapp.azurewebsites.net/ that provides a razor page that should be loaded into the container, while keeping menu and header (not reloading the whole page). so eg. I navigate to portal.ourcompany.com/integration1 and it would load the remote page from the azure function into the container.
There of course needs to be auth between the 2 (we use oauth2) (but Im pretty sure we know that bit)
Now I can see how to do this if we switch URLs and load whole page again, but thats not quite what we want.
any thoughts on how to do this? (if its even possible?)
I thought blazor routing could do this, but it appears Im wrong...
What we can do,** but do not want:
**
to move "seamlessly" between pages/urls keeping auth etc.
to keep same url and load a remote page using YARP
**What we want: **
to load the externally sourced .razor page into the container within the webassembly app without reloading the whole page.
In essence like having a "native" iframe.
EDIT: Clarification
Hi,
Thanks very much for taking the time to answer and ask for clarification, its appreciated. :)
So, to make it clear, what I want to achieve is this:
https://pasteboard.co/BixCfKD1xHnk.png
The Area in the red box currently loads a certain page, like portal.mycompany.com/Page1 without refreshing the header or menu - therefore being very fast and clean.
Currently each of the pages loads a set of blazor components which display data - mostly in the form of grids which then link to external pages. When we go to the external pages, it loads them from our legacy site (.net core) with a smooth transition but it does transfer to a different URL and load an entirely new page. Usually when clicking a link from the grid it will open a form, to input data about whatever object that was being displayed.
SO!
What I was hoping to do was load the content in the red box from an external server - in esssence making portal.mycompany.com/page1 load content from server1.mycompany.com/page1 while staying on portal.mycompany.com/page1 and not reloading the menu and header.

That's so confusing. Can you draw a schema for that? You want to load "razor file" from a different app? You mean like you have "Home" and "Counter", inside a "MainLayout". And you wish to load for example "Counter" from a different app/domain/solution?

I added an edit to try clarify, but yes, that is pretty much it.

Any luck with this? Sounds useful and interesting.

Sort of. What we have done for now is created nuget packages which it loads from the other domain, automated installs and is then part of the offline part of the site. Not ideal but it works for now.

You cannot "download and use" .razor page from different source, it has to be compiled first. Or you just want the generated html?
But maybe an iframe is what you looking for?

Thanks for the reply. As I mentioned, we speifically do not want an iframe.
What I really want is to set that the route /page1 in portal.mycompany.com is actually fetched from server1.ourcompany.com instead of portal.ourcompany.com. (as if it is part of the same project)
can the routing do that?

Oh, ok. I think I understand now.. So what about HttpClient and fetching from server1.ourcompany.com and using MarkupString?
You need to set the CORS properly on your server..
